# Django makemigrations wants to delete everything it just created

Tags: django, migration

I just followed this procedure:

- `makemigrations` (success)
- `migrate` (success)
- Copy the app on another server (with the migration files)
- Create a new empty database on that server
- `migrate` (success, it creates the correct schema)
- Fill the new database with data
- Just to test: `migrate` ....

At this point Django says I have `"changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied. Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them"`

But when I run `makemigrations`, it creates a new one that wants to "Remove field" every foreign key and "Delete model" all of my models. If I run it it empties my database. My `models.py` are intact.

What is happening ??

Comment: Django keeps track of all of the migrations in a database table in addition to those migration files. I cannot remember the table off the top of my head. but since you say you copied the app to another server, I'm willing to bet that since that migrations table is empty, that's why Django is telling you what you're seeing.

Comment: Does it only try to remove fields, or does it try to drop entire models? Does it try to recreate the same fields / models later in the migration / in a separate migration, or similar ones, just with a small difference?

Comment: The whole migration is only "Remove (foreign) field x" and "Delete model x", deleting all the models except the default django-admin and co. It does not recreate anything afterwards. If I make migrations again it tells me there is nothing to do. Since the first `migrate` was a success, it did create the django_migrations table and I see the migrations in it.

Comment: when you  Copying  the app on another server remove old migrations files except __init__.py and create new database and do makemigrations and migrate . hope it will be okay..

Comment: in my case it wants to remove a field that is not used in the app, but is used by a third party. Import doesn't seem to help since I can't import a field. 
Any idea where this is coming from?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in my project. Running forward I can say that django removes models that has no import (making the Delete model migration). The documentation says that you should import your model in the `myApp/models/__init__.py` file (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#organizing-models-in-a-package).

In my case I imported the model somewhere to make manipulations but model had been removing elsewhere.

I had made a useless import in an `admin.py` file that has solved my situation (I didn't try to follow the documentation and import it in the `__init__.py` but sure it should help). 
I had not realized yet why does it work that way (hope that someone could note this moment) and also hope this solution will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same errors, but I hit the `makemigrations` building a migration full of Remove Field and Delete Model commands before I tried the `migrate` command.

In my case, the solution was related this being an old project I was resurrecting, and it had a number of Model.Meta.app_name values set, as well as entries in `apps.py` for each project. These were now in conflict with the way settings was interpreting the project, and even though my models were imported into views and admin, they weren't being seen by the migration code. Deleting these app_name tags on the models, and modifying the AppConfig name in apps.py solved this, so that the running `makemigrations` again caused the expected changes (alter field, etc), and all was fine.

I didn't find any other questions or answers that quite matched this one and my experience, so I hope if anyone else looks for this, they'll find it here like I did ;-)